# calling a nested function in a class

Tags: matlab, class, oop, nested

```
classdef hello < handle
        methods
            function first(obj)
                a=4;
                function second(obj)
                    a
                end
            end
        end
end
```

I would like to be able to call the function "obj.second".

Here is what I have tried:

```
>> hello_obj=hello;
>> hello_obj.first
>> hello_obj.second
No appropriate method, property, or field second for class hello.

>> hello_obj.first.second
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

>> hello_obj.first.hello_obj.second
Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

Thank you

Comment: That is not possible, why do you think you have to do this?

Comment: I wanted to take advantage of the fact a nested function can access the workspace of its parent function (I don't want "a" to be a property).

Comment: `a` no longer exists when you try to call `second`. I think a property would be the best solution, but you may explain your reasons not to use a property. This might lead to a better solution.

Comment: For a very practical reason: as it's written, at the end of executions, my code saves the workspace (including the object), and I don't want "working" variables like this one to be saved.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Transient`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-attributes.html) property `a` to skip it when saving. For the cases where Transistent can't be applied, overloading the [`saveobj` and `loadobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/understanding-the-save-and-load-process.html) is a good alternative.

Comment: Can you please help me use it? Sorry.
classdef hello properties a=4 end properties (Transient=true) b=23 end end >> hello_obj=hello; >> save('hello_obj') hello_obj.mat contains an object which contains both properties.

Comment: @Michaël: No, it does not store the `b` in the mat file, it reinitializes using the constructor which sets it to 23. Try `hello_obj=hello;
hello_obj.a=5;
hello_obj.b=24;
save('hello_obj');
clear hello_obj;
load('hello_obj')`

Comment: Thank you! In fact, I don't want hello_obj.b to be saved at all, even as an empty variable.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please give an example of your data structure and what parts you want to save.

Comment: classdef hello properties a b end end >> hello_obj=hello; >> save('hello_obj') I don't want "b" to be saved, even as an empty variable.

Comment: Then the solution would be a dynamic property which is deleted in the `saveobj`. I can not provide any code, never used dynamic properties.